# pluginlib build fails: Unknown CMake command "catkin_add_gtest"

Tags: ros, catkin, pluginlib, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What am I missing that would cause this error? For background, I'm attempting to build the velodyne stack from source, because I may need to run the debugger in the future. I have built ros-fuerte from source and installed in /opt/ros/fuerte. I use rosws, roslocate, and rosmake to build stuff from source.

Update:
Here's how I built ros-fuerte:

```
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall
cd ~/ros-underlay
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
cd ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

That's pretty much what the ros wiki describes. I've left out installing necessary dependencies, of course. Running *rosversion ros* gives me 1.8.9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45348/pluginlib-build-fails:-unknown-cmake-command-%22catkin_add_gtest%22./) by [Bryce Hathaway](https://answers.ros.org/users/3344/bryce-hathaway/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-08**:
What versions of things have you installed where? Did you get the devel or release branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright. I have an answer. When I run

```
roslocate info pluginlib
```

it returns

```
- hg:
    local-name: pluginlib
    meta:
      repo-name: wg-kforge
    uri: https://kforge.ros.org/common/pluginlib
```

Notice there's no version information. So when I use this to update using rosws, I get latest, whereas I really want the one tagged as "fuerte". Once I got the matching version, I was able to build using rosmake. To my dismay, this procedure has failed for *geometry*, however, but that's a different question.

---

Originally posted by [Bryce Hathaway](https://answers.ros.org/users/3344/bryce-hathaway/) with karma: 36 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on 2012-11-16**:
Thanks. For geometry I noticed that I had to set the branch to "fuerte_devel" and the branch for bullet to "default". I posted a question about this.http://answers.ros.org/question/48328/error-class-btmatrix3x3-has-no-member-named-getrpy-when-building-tf/